# click a view on a customised sliding drawer content

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, buttonclick

I am working on an Android application. In my app I have to show a top to bottom sliding bar including lower versions.So I created a customized sliding drawer.Its works fine. Now I want to add a button on sliding drawer I have done that. Now I couldn't click on the button. I found the reason for not working click.
Please have a look on the following overrided method.

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent( MotionEvent event )
{
    if ( mLocked ) { return false; }

    final int action = event.getAction();

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    final Rect frame = mFrame;
    final View handle = mHandle;

    handle.getHitRect( frame );
    if ( !mTracking && !frame.contains( (int)x, (int)y ) ) { return false; }

    if ( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
        mTracking = true;

        handle.setPressed( true );
        // Must be called before prepareTracking()
        prepareContent();

        // Must be called after prepareContent()
        if ( mOnDrawerScrollListener != null ) {
            mOnDrawerScrollListener.onScrollStarted();
        }

        if ( mVertical ) {
            final int top = mHandle.getTop();
            mTouchDelta = (int)y - top;
            prepareTracking( top );
        } else {
            final int left = mHandle.getLeft();
            mTouchDelta = (int)x - left;
            prepareTracking( left );
        }
        mVelocityTracker.addMovement( event );
    }
            return true;

}
```

If I add the following code in to the onInterceptTouchEvent, then the button click works fine but the sliding functionality of sliding drawer doesn't work.

```
    if (mHandleLayout != null)
    {
int clickX = (int) (event.getX() - mHandleLayout.getLeft());
     int clickY = (int) (event.getY() - mHandleLayout.getTop());

        if (isAnyClickableChildHit(mHandleLayout, clickX, clickY))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

in simple if I return true then sliding works but button click dont. And If return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) then button click works but sliding functionality dont.

Please help me friends